# Why is the url property invalid in schema?

Tags: seo, schema.org, json-ld

I am trying to create an organization schema for the company given below
However, I am getting an error

I have tested the below code on Google Rich Results Testing Tool

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Svibo Industries",
    "url": "https: //sviboindustries.in",
    "logo": "https://sviboindustries.in/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/svibo-1.png",
    "image": "https://sviboindustries.in/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/svibo-1.png",
    "description": "Svibo Industries is broadly involved in manufacturing and supplying all types of Wire Ropes. Svibo provides all types of wire rope constructions of all grades.",
    "aggregateRating": {
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue": "4.9",
        "reviewCount": "355"
    },
    "areaServed": {
        "@type": "State",
        "name": "MH"
    },
    "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress": "111,112,113 Mahatma Phule Peth, Block No 101, Sevadham Building, 1st Floor, Pune, Maharashtra 411042",
        "addressLocality": "Pune",
        "addressRegion": "Maharashtra",
        "postalCode": "411042",
        "addressCountry": "India"
    },
    "hasOfferCatalog": {
        "@type": "OfferCatalog",
        "name": "Products",
        "itemListElement": [
            {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "Stainless Steel SS wire rope",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.9",
                    "reviewCount": "38"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "PVC Coated wire rope",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.9",
                    "reviewCount": "21"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "Galvanized wire rope",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.9",
                    "reviewCount": "10"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "Ungalvanized wire rope",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.9",
                    "reviewCount": "38"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "Polythene Slings",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.9",
                    "reviewCount": "40"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "Chain Sling and Alloy Chain",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.9",
                    "reviewCount": "40"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "Chain Pulley Block",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.9",
                    "reviewCount": "23"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "Lifting and Chain Hooks",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.9",
                    "reviewCount": "32"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "Electric Chain Hoist",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.9",
                    "reviewCount": "22"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "Eye Bolt",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.9",
                    "reviewCount": "15"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "Mini Electric Hoist",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.9",
                    "reviewCount": "32"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "Pulley, Pulleys Block and Chain Wheel",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.9",
                    "reviewCount": "56"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "Pulling and Lifting Machine",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.9",
                    "reviewCount": "21"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "Hand Puller",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.9",
                    "reviewCount": "10"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "Ratchet Lever Lifting Hoist",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.9",
                    "reviewCount": "32"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "Plate Lifting Clamps",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.9",
                    "reviewCount": "12"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "Trolley",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.9",
                    "reviewCount": "12"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "Winches",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.9",
                    "reviewCount": "32"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "Shackles",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.9",
                    "reviewCount": "40"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "Wire Rope Clamps",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.9",
                    "reviewCount": "31"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "Wire Rope Thimble",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.9",
                    "reviewCount": "42"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "Turnbuckle",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.9",
                    "reviewCount": "28"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "Safety Items",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.9",
                    "reviewCount": "15"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "contactPoints": [
        {
            "@type": "ContactPoint",
            "telephone": "+91 8208803755",
            "contactType": "Customer support",
            "email": "info@sviboindustries.com"
        },
        {
            "@type": "ContactPoint",
            "telephone": "+91 7447449114",
            "contactType": "Customer support"
        },
        {
            "@type": "ContactPoint",
            "telephone": "+91 9637545481",
            "contactType": "Customer support"
        }
    ]
}

</script>
```

Why does it show?
invalid value type for field "url"

Supported types: [http://schema.org/URL]

What value of url should I use?

What should be the format of the url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is due to space. This is your declaration:

```
"url": "https: //sviboindustries.in",
```

This is the correct declaration:

```
"url": "https://sviboindustries.in",
```